# does the findAll method impact my batch if there is many data in database table

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to export data from database table to CSV file.
my itemReader uses the findAll methods from the database table.

Is that will causes any problem if my query select extracts many records ?

Comment: "Is that will causes any problem if i have many records in database ?" Define how many...

Comment: @mrkernelpanic thanks. I have edited my post. I hope it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that will causes any problem if my query select extracts many records ?

Yes, the whole point of chunk processing in Spring Batch is avoid loading all data in memory. You can use the `JdbcPagingItemReader` or the `JdbcCursorItemReader` to read data in chunks.

Comment: I am using RepositoryItemReader using Spring Data JPA. is there any best practices for that? can the setPagingSize makes things better ? @Mahmoud Ben Hassine

Comment: Yes, definitely. Use the `pageSize` parameter to specify how many items to read in one page. This will avoid loading all data at once.